# How to load content for Sources Panel in Chrome DevTools? In Chrome 65.0.3325 it is initially blank

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

How to load content for  Sources Panel in Chrome DevTools? In Chrome 65.0.3325 it is initially blank while debugging [Demo](https://googlechrome.github.io/devtools-samples/debug-js/get-started) for Chrome Tutorial video: [DevTools 101: Debugging JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8)

Comment: The Sources panel has several sub-panels. Make sure `Network` sub-panel is selected.